# Why am I getting EXC BAD ACCESS when I don't use a local variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have this block of code which reads data from an AudioFileID into a buffer.

```
- (void)handle:(void *)aqData audioQueue:(AudioQueueRef) audioQueue buffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef) buffer
{
TestViewController *vc = (__bridge TestViewController *)aqData;

EDCAudioFile *file = vc.file;
UInt32 numPackets = file.numberOfPacketsToRead;
UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;

OSStatus err = AudioFileReadPacketData(file.audioFile, NO, &numBytesReadFromFile, vc.mPacketDescs, file.currentPacket, &numPackets, buffer->mAudioData);
```

Everything works fine when I declare a local variable in my method like this

```
EDCAudioFile *file = vc.file;
OSStatus err = AudioFileReadPacketData(file.audioFile, NO, &numBytesReadFromFile, vc.mPacketDescs, file.currentPacket, &numPackets, buffer->mAudioData);
```

EDCAudioFile is a class which contains a property of AudioFileID like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) AudioFileID audioFile;
```

But when I change this to

```
OSStatus err = AudioFileReadPacketData(vc.file.audioFile, NO, &numBytesReadFromFile, vc.mPacketDescs, file.currentPacket, &numPackets, buffer->mAudioData);
```

whereas vc contains this property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) EDCAudioFile *file;
```

it crashes with EXC BAD ACCESS Thread 1 address 0x4. The method is called like this when I have picked a song from a modal view controller and the method creates an audio queue with 16 buffers and fills them with audio data.

```
for (int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
    AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(self.mQueue, file.bufferByteSize, &_mBuffers[i]);
    handleOutputBuffer((__bridge void*) self, self.mQueue, _mBuffers[i]);
}

...

static void handleOutputBuffer (void *aqData, AudioQueueRef audioQueue, AudioQueueBufferRef buffer)
{
     TestViewController *vc = (__bridge TestViewController *)aqData;
     [vc handle:aqData audioQueue:audioQueue buffer:buffer];
}
```

It does crash when i=1 and for i=0 OSStatus reports an error with this code: 2003334207

NSZombie tells nothing and this code doesn't even crash on my IPhone 5 but on my iPad Mini. Method is invoked on the main thread.

As I said for first block of code everything is fine and I am able to play music on my iPhone and on my iPad.

I appreciate every help I can get.

Oh and here is my stack trace: 
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msWgE.jpg)

The reason behind this is that I followed this Apple Guide [Audio Queue Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQPlayback/PlayingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH3-SW2)
 to playback audio and now I want to try make it more object orientated by creating a class which contains all needed information since Apple uses a struct for that.

Comment: is your app multithreaded?

Comment: Yes but the execution of this code should be solely executed on the main thread. When my audio starts to play, a callback is invoked which is executed on a background thread. This callback fills the buffers but my code already crashes before any playing happens.

Comment: try using guard malloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just got it fixed by changing this line

```
- (void)handle:(void *)aqData audioQueue:(AudioQueueRef) audioQueue buffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef) buffer
```

to this

```
- (void)handle:(TestViewController *)aqData audioQueue:(AudioQueueRef) audioQueue buffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef) buffer
{
    UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;
    UInt32 numPackets = vc.file.numberOfPacketsToRead;

    AudioFileReadPacketData(vc.file.audioFile, NO, &numBytesReadFromFile, vc.packetDescs, vc.file.currentPacket, &numPackets, buffer->mAudioData);
```